# SwiftUI Modify Font of Picker View and Picker Choice List

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, picker

I'm trying to modify the fonts of a SwiftUI Picker. I believe I have tried adding modifiers to
all of the Picker initializer formats and none of them seem to have any effect. The only modification
I have found to work at all is the visible text when I wrap the Picker in a menu.

Here's some test code:

```
struct PickerFontView: View {

    @State private var years: [String] = ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019" ]
    @State private var selectedYear: String = "2015"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        
            Text("You chose:")
            Text("\(selectedYear)")
            
            //none of these font modifiers work in any initializer
            Picker("Choose a Year", selection: $selectedYear) {
                ForEach(years, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0).font(.title)
                }.font(.title)
            }.font(.title)
                .padding(.bottom)
        
            //only wrapping in Menu can I change font for display
            Menu {
                Picker("Choose a Year", selection: $selectedYear) {
                    ForEach(years, id: \.self) { y in
                        Text(y)
                    }
                }//picker
            } label: { Text(selectedYear).font(.title)} //this
        }
        .font(.system(size: 50))//does not affect the non-menu picker
    
    }
}
```

This is the view:

[image]

This is what I would like to modify:

[image]

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 14.2 iOS 16.2

Comment: I think the fonts as you have them, only works for `.pickerStyle(.wheel)` not the default `menu`.

Comment: Interesting, yes I see that it does not work in my setup but I do find it curious that the above code doesn't break anything. And yes, I changed to the .wheel and the Text($0).font(.title) works. But I still need a solution for my situation!